# SQL Server : create a column as an Identity that repeats a pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

In SQL Server 2008 R2 I know how to create a primary key column that keeps my lines unique (column3 in my example below), but I also need a column that auto-fills a repeating set of integers (column2 in my example below).

I don't know how to create a column like this. Searches suggest it can be done with "reseeding", but not sure how to actually a create this column or if its even possible to automatically do this.

I'm looking for something like this, with Column2 being auto-filled every time a new line is created:

```
Column1   Column2  Column3
name1     1        1
name2     2        2
name3     3        3
name4     4        4
name5     5        5
name6     1        6
name7     2        7
name8     3        8
name9     4        9
name10    5        10
name11    1        11
name12    2        12
```

Comment: How is column 2 determined? You cannot use reseeding for this purpose.

Comment: What about using a trigger ?  Since you have an identity column, you could search the current value at max(column3) and then perform some logic, like "let column2 be (last value + 1), or 1 if (last value == 5)...

Comment: I literally just want a repeating pattern of 1 through 5.  Determined by the number of rows and nothing else.  I'm not sure if what I want is possible natively.

Comment: Do you need to store the value or can you calculate it?

Comment: @CristianMeneses that sounds like what I'm talking about.  If for example I deleted a row in my example, I would still want Column2 to count 1 through 5 dynamically.  (i.e. if I removed the row for name3, then name4's row would have "3" in column 2)

Comment: Depending on number of rows or identity value in Column3? Those will differ after a time if you delete rows

Comment: @Namphibian It could be calculated.  I want row #5 to always have 5 in the value of column2, and row #10 would always have 5 in the value of column2.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Correct, I don't care what happens to the value in Column3 that is just used as a Primary Key to keep the rows unique.  I don't use that column for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a persisted column by doing something along these lines:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD Column2 AS (Column3 % 5)
```

While I think this will give you 0-4 instead of 1-5, it should put you on the right track to do some mathyness on Column3 to create the column you are looking for.

For a constantly updating answer that updates if rows are removed, you could do something like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTableValue
(
    @Index int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int
    SELECT @Result = COUNT(*) % 5
        FROM dbo.TABLE
        WHERE PrimaryKey < @Index

    RETURN @Result
END
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD CalcValue AS (dbo.GetTableValue(PrimaryKey));
```

That query isn't fully tested but should put you on the right path. Once again, this will hurt performance in a larger database due to the query executing on every read from the DB.

Comment: 0 through 4 would work the same for my needs as 1 through 5.  So if that works then that would be what I need.  But I don't believe I can base column2 off of column3 because I can't know what value column3 will have.  If I delete a row, the integer in column3 is deleted.

Comment: Curse this crummy laptop... What I was trying to say is that deleting a row will break your sequence: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f28cf/2

Comment: @PaulGriffin You are correct.  I thought my test proved otherwise, but if I delete a ROW it does indeed break the numbering.  So its not dynamic like I hoped.  I can use this if I have to, but hopefully someone can provide an alternative.

Comment: @Martin Noreke I'm going to temporarily hold off marking this as answered since its not the dynamic solution I had hoped for, but if no one else provides a better solution I will later make it answered as it sort of works for what I need.

Comment: @WilliamJenkins: It actually is quite dynamic and calculates the value based upon the current value in Column3. If you try it with a non-identity column where you can update the value, if you do an update on the value you are calculating on, the result of this column updates as well.

If on the other hand you are wanting to count the number of indexes that are less than this record in order to figure out what the value is, then you need to do a function that gets called by the column in order to do that calculation.

Comment: Is there a syntax that would base Column2 off of Row # rather than Column3?  Something along the lines of `ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD Column2 AS (ROW % 5)`

Comment: You could define a function that takes the rowID, and returns the final calculated value based upon how many rowIDs are less. However, now you are venturing into dangerous performance territories as every query ends up calling a function that does a (select count(*) from table where ID < @providedID) or similar.

Comment: @Martin Noreke I meant it was non-dynamic in the sense the if I delete (for example) row #2 then the 0-1-2-3-4 is now 0-2-3-4. for existing rows.  You are correct that if I create a new row it dynamically creates the new row with the right number.  So I hope I'm not insulting you, but it wasn't 100% what I had hoped for.

Comment: @WilliamJenkins: Not at all. I tried to clarify in my last two statements (function based) on how you could achieve your 100% solution as well. Let me know if you need a sample for that and I'll try to put that together for you tomorrow.

Comment: @Martin Noreke  What would the query look like to regenerate the numbering sequence on the already created column?  For my needs it doesn't have to be that dynamic.  If i could re-run a query every so often to "refresh" the numbering that would work too.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or 2014, you can (and should) use a [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.FiveCount
  AS tinyint
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CYCLE
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 5
;
```

Then define the next value of the `SEQUENCE` as the default value of the column:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
    ([Column1] varchar(6), 
     [Column2] int CONSTRAINT DF_testTable_col2 DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR FiveCount, 
     [Column3] int)
;
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/779da/1) of this `SEQUENCE` being created, followed by a series of inserts, then a select all to show the results of the insertions.

EDIT: Note that inserting the results into the table like this means that the sequence will be broken if a row is deleted.

A more dynamic approach might be something like the following (assuming the sequence is already in place):

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
     [Column1] varchar(6), 
     [Column3] int
);
```

Then, when you want to select from the table:

```
SELECT
  Column1,
  NEXT VALUE FOR FiveCount AS Column2,
  Column3
FROM test_table
```

This query would ensure that you always get an unbroken sequence, regardless of the state of `test_table`

If it is important that the `SEQUENCE` always begin with 1, you can `RESTART` it like so:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.FiveCount RESTART WITH 1
```

[Here's a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10768/3) of the `SEQUENCE` being restarted, followed by the select query, followed by a deletion from `test_table`, followed by another instance of the restart and select query.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing this with SQL 2008 R2.  I should have mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: These sorts of problems are notoriously difficult to solve with triggers, sequence tables, and so on, and are why the `SEQUENCE` object was added to 2012 in the first place.  You might take a look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx

Comment: For the record, persisting the value into a column like this will also be broken by a deleted record.  I believe you should be able to dynamically select from the sequence instead.  I will post an addendum to the answer once I get back to a computer and double check

Answer (score 1):

Instead of persisting the sequence, can you set the sequence when you query the data? This would likely be much better for server health if your table is heavily used. This would also allow you to always have consistent sequences in your data.

If you need a 1-5 sequence, use a case statement along with your modulus:

```
Select
    Column1
    ,Case When Row_number() Over(order by Column1)%5 =0 
          Then 5 
          Else Row_number() Over(order by Column1)%5 
    End as Column2
    ,Row_number() Over(order by ID) as Column3
From TableName
```