# Table design increment a column for each unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Say I have a Customer table

```
id  |  customerId
1       569
2       569
1       577 
1       555
2       555
3       555
```

On each insert I want id increment by one depend on the customerId column. I have prepared my insert sp as below, but I wonder if there is a native way to make my table behave like this (when creating table with any constraints).

```
ALTER dbo.ins_Customer
@CustomerId INT
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @MaxSeqId INT
   SELECT @MaxSeqId = MAX(id) FROM dbo.Customer 
   WHERE customerId = @CustomerId 
   INSERT INTO dbo.Customer VALUES (@MaxSeqId+1, @CustomerId)
END
```

I want this simple insert statement produce the result above with any possible, native constraints.

```
ALTER dbo.ins_Customer
@CustomerId INT
AS 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Customer VALUES (@CustomerId)
END
```

Comment: I believe you want the [IDENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777734/how-do-i-add-a-auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-database) column type.

Comment: Yes I want Identity but for each `CustomerId`. Id will increment for each **any** record , but I want for each customerId. I mean customerId and id will be unique together.

Comment: What version of sql? For 2012 onward you may want to look at [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql). For a good post on it, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954705/6167855)

Comment: This cannot be done as part of the table definition. You'd have to use a trigger to set the values using the ROW_NUMBER function.

Comment: @scsimon As I need to create a sequence for each customerId, sequnce will not work here I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a native way to make my table behave like this
>   (when creating table with any constraints).

No, there is not.  You will have to write custom code to make your table behave like this.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just use `row_number()` on any query... no need to make this a permanent column

```
select
   row_number() over (partition by customerId order by (select 1)) as ID
  ,customerId
from
   yourTable
```

Note, this is often done in a `VIEW` so you don't have to update / alter your table.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the answer, I have updated the question, I want the simple insert statement to give the result that I show.