# Duplicate key violation with composite primary key on high frequency insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Alg].[Sequence](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SequenceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [text] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sequence] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SequenceId] ASC,
    [CustomerId] ASC
)
```

And this is a block from insert/update trigger of another table where I insert data to `Sequence` table:

```
--insert data into sequence table
SELECT @MaxSeqId =  ISNULL(MAX(SequenceId),0)
FROM Alg.[Sequence] WITH (ROWLOCK)
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId

INSERT INTO Alg.[Sequence]
VALUES (
@MaxSeqId + 1
,@CustomerId
,@SendingData
,GETDATE()
)
```

So whenever high frequency insertion processes (on the table with trigger), violation of duplicate  key error occurs. I tried `ROWLOCK`, but didn't work. How can I prevent this from happenning?

**Update**

I have been asked why I am not using built-in sequence, I tried but couldn't find how to use sequence with composite primary key. I don't want the SequenceId column be identity, in fact, **I would like to keep SequenceId as identity for each CustomerId.** You can see my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45941521/2289430) related with this

Comment: Why would you want to create your own Sequence table? It's recommended to use the Sequence Objects. Find more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql

Comment: Doesn't `IDENTITY(1,1)` do the incrementing for you, therefore you don't need to insert it?  Asking for a friend.

Comment: I have updated the question related sequence object.

Comment: You absolutely can and should use a sequence here.  I don't pretend to know what your objective is (nor do I understand your objection) but you are in fact recreating a broken version of a sequence.  If you can (almost) do it with the code you wrote then you can do it properly with a sequence.  A sequence is just another way to get a unique integer.  That is all.  You will still get a usable sequence number for each customer, it just happens that it will also be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a poor design.  You should really use sequences.  Really.

One of the reasons this is a poor design is that it's easy to get bugs like the one you have.  Here's how to make that code actually work:

```
begin transaction

SELECT @MaxSeqId =  ISNULL(MAX(SequenceId),0)
FROM Alg.[Sequence] WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId

INSERT INTO Alg.[Sequence](SequenceId, CustomerId, Data)
VALUES (
@MaxSeqId + 1
,@CustomerId
,@SendingData
)

commit transaction
```

UPDLOCK instructs SQL Server to place a restrictive lock on the rows read, and to ignore the version store.  SERIALIZABLE instructs SQL to use range locking, so that even if no row is found, a U lock is taken on the key range to prevent a concurrent SELECT from discovering that there is no row until the first session performs the INSERT and commits the transaction.

A *slightly* better pattern is to use a Application Lock around the sequence generator, calling [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) before generating the key, and then calling [sp_releaseapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-releaseapplock-transact-sql) immediately afterword.  Then concurrent sessions wouldn't have to wait until the first session's transaction to commit before generating the next key value.

Comment: Thanks David, I updated my question why I couldn't use sequence objects, as I indicate on my update I need the SequenceId behave as identity for each different CustomerId.  I guess your last paragraph suggest an approach using sequences and is this consistent with my case?

Comment: Yes the script above which adds extra `UPDLCOK` and `SERIALIZABLE` is working, however I would love to see an example with sequence object which guarantees seperate sequenceId increment for each customerId without any violation.

Comment: @ibubi A [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) can't be used that way, it is just one sequence and can't be subdivided for several categories (e.g. by customer ID). If you really need such a construct I would advise creating a counter table (see link in my answer).

Comment: The usual solution is to remove the "requirement" for each customer to have their own sequence, and use a single sequence across all customers.  It's ultimately irrelevant if a customer's orders are numbered 1,2,4,5, . . .  or 1923,2334,2556,5585, . . ..  Alternatively you can provision a sequence for each customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following intead:

```
SELECT @MaxSeqId =  ISNULL(MAX(SequenceId),0)
FROM Alg.[Sequence] WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId

INSERT INTO Alg.[Sequence]
VALUES (
@MaxSeqId + 1
,@CustomerId
,@SendingData
,GETDATE()
)
```

This will keep a lock on the sequence table (either a range lock or a table lock) until the transaction completes. Do make sure this runs in a transaction. If as you say this is run from inside a trigger, this should be implicit.

Note that determining the maximum ID this way is not efficient. Maybe an `IDENTITY` column would suffice if you don't mind the occasional gap in numbering. If you don't want gaps maybe a counter table can help (an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35418227/243373)).

Comment: Note HOLDLOCK is equivalent to SERIALIZABLE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table